# Using ExpressJS with NextJS 13 to serve static files uploaded to the public folder

Tags: express, next.js, next.js13

before Next.js 13 and while using the pages folder. I found a solution to serve static files that are uploaded even after the build which is

this solution

Folder : /api/uploads/[dirname]/[name].js

```
export const config = {
    api: { externalResolver: true }
 }
 
 import express from 'express';
 const handler = express();
 
 const serveFiles = express.static(process.cwd()+"/public/uploads/");
 handler.use(['/api/uploads', '/uploads'], serveFiles);
 

 export default handler;
```

the soltuion used to work perfectly but now with Next.JS 13. I can't find a way to apply it! Is there anything I can do to make it work?

I tried writing the same code and playing with the folders but it doesn't work